# include and remove products from a table with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

how i can include and remove a list of products from a table with AngularJS? 
i select an product in a select list, and set the amount, in amount, then i click add, to add in a table.

http://jsfiddle.net/hqWW7/

HTML:

```
<label>Select a product</label>
<select>
    <option>select...</option>
    <option>value 1</option>
    <option>value 2</option>
    <option>value 3</option>
    <option>value 4</option>
    <option>value 5</option>
</select>
<br>
<label>Amount</label>
<input type="text" name="amount">
    <button type="button">ADD</button>
    <br>
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Product</td>
                <td>Amount</td>
                <td>Remove</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a href="">x</a></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 50%;
}

table thead {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: arial;
}

table tbody {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <script>
     angular.module("myApp", ['ngResource'])
    .controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.products = [
            {name: "apple", amount: "111"},
            { name: "orange", amount: "222"}
        ];
        $scope.addProduct = function () {
            $scope.products.push({name: $scope.myModel1, amount: $scope.myModel2, })
        }
        $scope.removeProduct = function (productToRemove) {
            var index = $scope.products.indexOf(productToRemove);
            $scope.products.splice(index, 1);
        }
    })
    </script>

    <!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <label>Select a product</label>
    <select ng-model="myModel1">
        <option>select...</option>
        <option>value 1</option>
        <option>value 2</option>
        <option>value 3</option>
        <option>value 4</option>
        <option>value 5</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label>Amount</label>
    <input type="text" name="amount" ng-model="myModel2">
    <button type="button" ng-click="addProduct()">ADD</button>
    <br>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Amount</td>
            <td>Remove</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
            <td>{{product.name}}</td>
            <td>{{product.amount}}</td>
            <td ng-click="removeProduct()"><a href="#">X</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can add a message "no products added yet" if none product was added?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a controller.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Than you need to create a method in your controller that pushing your item and amount to an array. Assign that function to your button click via:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

In your html you need to loop your array in order to add your record to table.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

There is many things needs to be done for what you are asking. Please check the docs, if you don't understand or face with an error of yourse you can ask again.